# Retrieve data variables in options properties in Vue.js / Vue-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-select

i need some help with vue.

1. Is it possible to call data variables in options properties? For example in "price" property I would like to call data variable "tax".
2. And how to return a single options property in a function, in my case function is called "final", i tried return this.selected.test, but it is not working

Here is the code:

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: null,
    tax: 0.07,
    mrg: 0.11,
    ex_mrg: 0.16,
    qnt: '',
    options: [{
      label: 'Item 1',
      id: 1,
      price: '* Price: ' + '$' + 0.26 + ' per one printed item',
      test: 5,
      env: 0.026,
      ltrhd: '',
    }, {
      test: 6,
      label: 'Item 2',
      id: 2,
      price: '* Price: ' + '$' + 7.35 + ' per one printed item',
      shrt: 7.351
    }, {
      test: 7 * 7,
      label: 'Item 3',
      id: 3,
      price: '* Price: ' + '$' + 0.96 + ' per one printed item',
      frsb: 0.969269,
      yoyo: 0.3658
    }, ]
  },
  computed: {
    selectedId() {
      return this.selected ? this.selected.id : null;
    },
    priceId() {
      return this.selected ? this.selected.price : null;
    },
    result: function() {
      return this.tax * this.mrg * this.qnt;
    },
    final: function() {
      return this.selected;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.11"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.3.1"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Please, select item</h1>
  <v-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></v-select><br>
  <p>Quantity needed:</p>
  <input type="number" name="trade-in" v-model.number="qnt" />
  <p>{{ priceId }}</p>
  <h1>selectedId: {{ selectedId }}</h1>
  <p>{{ qnt }}</p>
  <p>Final price: ${{ result }}</p>
  <p>Final price: {{ final }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your second question. can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for that. I would like to display the property "test" everytime when i select an item. Even better would be to merge/calculate "test" variable with data variable "tax" for example, so i get displayes the final result

Comment: Yeah, I figured i out. I'm just writting the answer

Comment: You can check the demo now. And let me know if that is what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see answers below

> 1. Is it possible to call data variables in options properties? For
>      example in "price" property I would like to call data variable "tax".

You cannot, but you can do following. Make your data a `function` and declare a tax `variable`, that `variable` you can use at multiple places.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() { 
    var tax = 0.07;
    return {
      tax: tax,,
      options: [{
        label: 'Item 1',
        id: 1,
        price: '* Price: ' + '$' + (0.26 + tax) + ' per one printed item',
        test: 5,
        env: 0.026,
        ltrhd: '',
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

> 2. And how to return a single options property in a function, in my case
>      function is called "final", i tried return this.selected.test, but it
>      is not working

Initially your `this.selected` is null. That is why you code is throwing exception when you did `this.selected.test`. Try following

```
final: function(){
      return this.selected && this.selected.test;
}
```

Comment: Great! that was the thing that I was looking for! Thank you. One more question, do you maybe know how to add line break in the "price" property? i already tried \n or <br>

Comment: For that you have to use `<p v-html="priceId"></p>` instead of `<p>{{ priceId }}</p>`. Please upvote or mark accepted if this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Make `data:{}` a function. i.e it should be `data () {}`

second the reason you are not getting `this.selected.test` is because, initially your `this.selected` is null. So, once the page loads your computed property tries to fetch `test` from this null data.

third. If you want use the tax property inside your `options`, you should consider making a property options that returns the options plus the tax all computed.

Here is a working example.

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      selected: null,
      tax: 0.07,
      mrg: 0.11,
      ex_mrg: 0.16,
      qnt: '',
    }
  },
computed: {
  options () {
    return   [{
      label: 'Item 1',
      id: 1,
      price: this.tax + '$' + 0.26 + ' per one printed item',
      test: 5,
      env: 0.026,
      ltrhd: '',
    }, {
      test: 6,
      label: 'Item 2',
      id: 2,
      price:  this.tax  + '$' + 7.35 + ' per one printed item',
      shrt: 7.351
    }, {
      test: 7*7,
      label: 'Item 3',
      id: 3,
      price: this.tax  + '$' + 0.96 + ' per one printed item',
      frsb : 0.969269,
      yoyo : 0.3658
    }]
  },
      selectedId() {
    return this.selected ? this.selected.id : null;
    },
    priceId() {
    return this.selected ? this.selected.price : null;
      
    },
    result: function(){
    return this.tax * this.mrg * this.qnt;
    },
  final () {
    return this.selected ? this.selected.test : false;
  }
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.3.1/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <h1>Please, select item</h1>
  <v-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></v-select><br>
  <p>Quantity needed:</p>
  <input type="number" name="trade-in" v-model.number="qnt" />
  <p>{{ priceId }}</p>
  <h1>selectedId: {{ selectedId }}</h1>
  <p>{{ qnt }}</p>
  <p>Final price: ${{ result }}</p>
  <p>Final price: {{ final }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, it is working! Thank you, that's what I wanted.